# Speakers of Macbook Air 2010 model not working

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones, speakers

I have a 13 inch macbook air 2010 model purchased 3 years ago.

In the past year my speakers are not working.

The speaker icon shows fine, but only there is no sound. More puzzling thing is, while switching on my mac after a shut down, I am getting the OS launch sound perfectly fine. But after that no sound.

Even the headphones are not working, with some muffled sound when i insert in to jack.

Since then I am using blue tooth headphones for past one year.

When I consulted a Apple service center they told that the the mother board itself should be changed, which costs around 30,000 rupees. I just got used to and stopped thinking about it.

One other thing to mention is, the output source is always headphones, even without any headphones in the jack.

Now , after seeing this website, I am just curious if someone has any solution for this.

Comment: we need to find out if some app is taking over your sound control. for that you need to look in your sound settings. just to make sure, disable the BT for this.

Comment: [If it's a hardware issue] Check with other stores around your city in India, for a hardware replacement.

Comment: If you haven't already, reinstall your operating system. It sounds fishy that the OS boot rings fine. This makes me think that it is a software based issue.

Comment: TRY: Hold ALT and click the speaker icon. Can you select a different source?

Comment: @Rob Actually i hold alt and clicked sound icon. What i noticed is, the output device is headphones which is ticked even without any headphone inserted in to the jack

Comment: @d0ct0r can you select the built-in speakers?

Comment: No, its not showing in the output options @Rob

Answer (score 1):

Lets do some problem hunting, and hopefully repairing (without replacing the logic board).

Since the speakers work for System Sound, and the BT headset works.

Open Audio Midi set up app in your utility folder.

In the check for settings on the left window.

Normally it would only have this setting

[image: midi]

If you have any other profiles showing or been active disable them.

Comment: I don't have any other profiles apart from built in microphone and built in output.